# XHR object creation

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

What difference between:

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
```

and

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
```

?
If I correctly understand, each of this two cases create XRH object.

Comment: `getXmlHttp()` is something you write. `new XMLHttpRequest()` is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this function:

```
function getXMLHttp() {
    var x = false;
    try {
        x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e) {
        try {
            x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(ex) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1) {
                x = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

`getXMLHttp()` is your custom function to simplify the creation an `XHR` object with the cross browser issues.

`XMLHttpRequest` is an object to used with the current modern browser. For the old browser like IE5 or IE6, you can use `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");`

However, the return object is the same for each browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up Chrome Developer tools and try the following:

```
> getXmlHttp()
ReferenceError: getXmlHttp is not defined
```

This indicates that `getXmlHttp` is not a built in function.

Comment: If I add code
  `function getXMLHTTP() {
     var x = false;
     try {
       x = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }catch(e) {
         try {
           x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(ex) {
               try {
                 req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
               }
               catch(e1) {
                 x = false;
               }
             }
         }
       return x;
     }`

it also return XMLHttpRequest object?